# Определения функций в хедере

Tags: c++, c

Какие функции исходного файла должны быть декларированы в хедере? Только те, которые используются в других исходных файлах, или вообще все?

Comment: Возможно, вы хотели спросить, какие функции должны быть продекларированы в заголовочном файле?

Comment: Определены или объявлены? Понимаете разницу?

Comment: С: только функции доступные другим модулям (только API) должны быть **объявлены** (не определены) в заголовочном файле.

Comment: С++:  тоже что и C и ещё все шаблонные фунцкии (и шаблонные классы и всё остальное шаблонное) должны быть **определены** (не только объявлены) в заголовочном файле.

Comment: Вопрос смешивает два разных языка, которые требуют двух длинных различных ответов с примерами. :(

Answer (score 0):

В хедере должны быть декларированы функции, которые используются в других исходных файлах. Если функция используется только внутри данного исходного файла, то декларация не обязательна.

Comment: Плохой совет: детали реализации замусоривают глобальное пространство имён, нарушают инкапсуляцию, создают конфликты при компиляции и сборке.